Azure Open AI ingestion job API is not working the secure network
We have implemented Azure open AI With our data, followed by the below link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/how-to/use-your-data-securely
Now we have integrated the below API (Create and Get) in a web job to create the index over a new file.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azureopenai/ingestion-jobs?view=rest-azureopenai-2023-10-01-preview
Create API required storage account connection string as a parameter and our storage account public access is disabled Now
Status code: {"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Resource validation failed. Provided storage container does not exist or credentials are invalid."}}
we are getting an error for the storage connection and firewall.
Please help in this scenario on how can we pass the storage connection string.
Thanks in advance.
By updating connection string

This error Resource validation failed. Provided storage container does not exist or credentials are invalid occurs when the storage account is not accessible or the user doesn't have sufficient access to write to the storage account.
Plan 1:
To isolate this issue, you can first check if enabling access from all network resolves this issue.

Plan 2:
If you wish to allow the access to your Storage Account from your client machine, like using Azure OpenAI Studio or invoking the REST API, you need to create private endpoint connection that connects to your blob storage.
More info here.
Hope this helps.
